# How to add in the simplest way Google service to applications [Java, libGDX]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I develop apps for Android using libGDX and I want to add Google services such as Google Games or Goodle Ads but I can't do it. I downloaded Google services with SDK Manager and read many guides but none of them have helped. When I try to add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3+'` to **build.gradle** it pops up errors. Hence my question is how to simply add google service to applications. I program in Android Studio.

Comment: Did you follow the steps described here? http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: You're going to need to be a lot more specific and detailed if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad so I can't give you an exact answer.

[This](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX) is the official place to go if you want to incorporate google play services.

[This](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-%28replaces-deprecated-AdMob%29) is the place to go if you want to include google play ads service

Note that Intellij Idea is pretty much the same as Android Studio. Whatever works for Idea works for Android Studio in this case.